# Is there any flaw in the logic of this problem?

Tags: c++, algorithm

The problem is find the number of factors of (N!)^2.

This is the code, I wrote:

```
int prime[]={//list of primes <(10^6)};
int num_fac_of_factorial(int n, int x)
{
    int p=x, z=0;
    while(n/p>0)
    {
        z+=n/p;
        p*=x;
    }
    return z;
}

int count=78498;   //Count of prime numbers <10^6

int main()
{
    int n, x, first=0, m=1000007;
    long long sol=1;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(int i=0; prime[i]<=n && i<count; i++)
    {
        x=num_fac_of_factorial(n, prime[i]);
        x=2*x+1;
        sol=(sol*x)%m;
    }
    sol%=m;
    printf("%d\n", sol);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no flaw in the logic, just a couple of implementation errors. And if e.g. `1/10 + 1/15 = 1/6` and `1/15 + 1/10 = 1/6` shall not be counted as different solutions but as one, then of course you need `(1 + number of divisors)/2`.

Here

```
for(int i=0; prime[i]<=n && i<count; i++)
```

you ought to check `i < count` before accessing `prime[i]`. If `n > 999983`, you will try to access `prime[78498]`, which is undefined behaviour.

And - assuming that `int` is as usual 32 bits (or 36, wouldn't apply to 64-bit `int`s, however) - here

```
int num_fac_of_factorial(int n, int x)
{
    int p=x, z=0;
    while(n/p>0)
    {
        z+=n/p;
        p*=x;
    }
    return z;
}
```

you have overflow for large enough primes `x` (typically `> 46340`) when calculating `x*x`, which is also undefined behaviour. And with the not uncommon wrap-around for `int` overflow, that will cause wrong results for `n >= 65537`. Replace the `while` loop with

```
do {
    n /= x;
    z += n;
while(n > 0);
```

to avoid the overflow.

Comment: For the first time, I am glad that someone pointed out so many implementation errors in my code. :P
Btw, as per the question I need not do (1 + no_of_divisors)/2. That's fine.
The i<count should have been before prime[i]<=n. And your point about the int overflow is also right. Thanks for pointing all this out.

Comment: Two glitches. You have an interesting definition of 'many' ;)

Comment: When you are quite experienced and suddenly make silly mistakes, 'two' indeed is 'many'. :)